Difficulty retrieving batch results from Google Cloud Datastore in PHP 7.4
On a PHP 7.4 project, I'm using the google/cloud-datastore:1.24 library to interact with my Datastore database. I would like to retrieve results in batches, with a specific size, and consequently make as many queries as needed until there is no more data to retrieve from the datastore.
Here's what I've tried:
    $datastoreClient = new DatastoreClient([
       'projectId' => 'project_id',
       'namespaceId' => 'my-namespace'
    ]);
    $query = $datastoreClient->query(/* ... */)
    
    $pageSize = 500;
    $result = array();
    $queryContinueFetch = true;
    $queryNumIteration = 0;
    
    do {
        $query->limit($pageSize)->offset($queryNumIteration * $pageSize);
    
        $resultQuery = $datastoreClient->runQuery($query);
        $queryContinueFetch = iterator_count($resultQuery) > 0;
        
        foreach ($resultQuery as $index => $history) {
            /* ... */
        }
    
        $queryNumIteration++;
    } while($queryContinueFetch);

The issue with my code is that iterator_count may not retain the current position as indicated in the PHP documentation here:

Count the elements in an iterator. iterator_count() is not guaranteed
to retain the current position of the iterator.

Therefore, when I call the iterator_count function, the cursor is moved to the end, and as a result, I cannot process any data within the loop because of the iterator_count function.
I'm using iterator_count because runQuery returns a class EntityIterator implementing the Iterator interface. Therefore, I use iterator_count to know if there is any remaining data to retrieve from the Datastore.
Do you have any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Why don't you just set a flag inside foreach to know that at least one element has been processed?

@Olivier Yes, I could do that, but I hadn't thought of it. And do you think there would be a better way of doing it than what I've done (like the sliders, for example) ?
